# Controlling the Asset video bit-rate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`/`AVCaptureSession` for video capture ( based on the AVCam sample ).
**My target OS version is iOS 4.3**, having that in mind, Is there any way to control the video bit-rate ( `AVVideoAverageBitRateKey` ) through `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`/`AVCaptureSession`, OR, should I drill deeper into AVAssetsWriter ?

**P.S.**
I need fine control over the bit-rate so 'AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset' is not adequate, rather, I would like to directly control `AVVideoAverageBitRateKey`.

~Nadav

Comment: Was done using AVAsserWriter in accordance to [this][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257052/avcapturesession-only-got-video-buffer

Comment: Was successfully done using AVAsserWriter in accordance to [this][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257052/avcapturesession-only-got-video-buffer